# Cannot checkout file and associate to a pending changelist using p4 python

Tags: python, perforce, p4python

```
try: # Catch exceptions with try/except
    p4.connect() # Connect to the Perforce Server
    p4.run_login()

    client = p4.fetch_client()
    client['View'] = ['//TestPublic/Extern/firanl/... //mitica/TestPublic/Extern/firanl/...']  # workspace mapping
    p4.save_client(client)
#    p4.run_sync()   # this command stops the execution of other commands after this

    result = p4.run("fstat", perforce_path)[0]
    file1 = result['clientFile']

    change = p4.fetch_change()
    change._files = [file1]     #associate file to changelist
    change._description = 'aaaaaa'
    p4.run_submit(change)



    p4.disconnect() # Disconnect from the Server
except P4Exception:
    for e in p4.errors: # Display errors
        print e
```

#

When I run the code, will give me this error: 
"Error in change specification.
Can't include file(s) not already opened.
Open new files with p4 add, p4 edit, etc."

I tried to open the file with p4.run("edit", file1), but the program does nothing and doesn't run the next commands after this.
How do I open the file and what are the python working commands for p4 add and p4 edit?

Comment: Running "p4 edit" is the right thing to do.  Time to debug: 1) Print the value of "file1" to make sure it's something reasonable.  2) Try running "p4 edit (file1)" from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

Focus on your `run_sync` command. My guess is that it's not using the client you've just set up.

To verify what *is* getting used, run `run_set` and print its results.

To make sure you're using your client, first give it a name (using `client['Name'] = 'MyClient'`) before saving it and then tell your P4Python to use it (`p4.client = 'MyClient'`).

Then run your sync.